# SD card reader does not work after upgrading to Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, hardware, driver, sd-card

I have upgraded my Mac Book pro MB991 (13-inch, Mid 2009) to OS X Mountain Lion. After that the system does not show any reaction on inserting or ejecting an SD card.

The card itself works well with my camera.

I checked Disk Utility and About my Mac but it's not displayed there:
[image: screenshot of Disk Utility]
[image: screenshot of About my Mac]

iStat Pro doesn't show it neither:
[image: screenshot of iStats Pro widget]

I have Parallels Desktop 7 and Vmware Fusion installed on my mac so may be problem is related to the drivers supplied with those software.

Does any one know how to fix this or at least how to dig deeper to get any new information?

Comment: Have you tried more than one card? What is the brand of the card(s) you're trying? What kind of camera are you using to format the card and have you formatted it recently? Maybe it's the card, not the reader, good to try another one before going too deeply into the computer.

Comment: This card works with a different macbook, so it's definitely not a card. It's a SanDisk card and a Nikon camera.

Comment: Have you tried another card in the reader? Do all cards fail?

Comment: No, I have not. I have just one card that works perfectly everywhere but with my laptop.

Comment: Maybe consider buying another card to test. They're inexpensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motherboard got broken. That was the reason of the problem. Now the system does not see one of the memory slots too. The solution is to get a new motherboard.

Sorry guys for bothering you.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have the same problem with the SD card not showing up but when I opened iPhoto it just loaded my photo's off of my sd card. I have a sandisk SD card. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've selected the option to show the SD-cards in Finder?
*Finder < Preferences < external disks/CDs, DVDs & iPod*.

[image]

I'm not sure this will solve your question concerning the Disk Format, but it might help you out in the Finder view...